# Intranet name resolution in docker container

Tags: macos, docker, teamcity, kitematic

I use docker beta (version 1.12.0-rc3-beta18 build: 9996) on OS X (10.11.5) for learning docker.

I installed jetbrains/teamcity-server as docker container and two agents (on the same OSX machine and on Win 10 client).

The Git repositories are on own local server (TFS 2015 Update 2). If use the git-Address with the IP-Address, all works fine. If I use the server name, this name con not be resolved.

Resolving of internet addresses (github, bitbucket) works.

I tried to pass the intranet DNS-Server-Address as `--dns=DNS_IP_ADDRESS` parameter to the run command, but without success.

What should I do for the docker container to be able to resolve names in local network?

**Update 1:**

```
nbrw:~ buildagent$ dig @192.168.149.25 devteam

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @192.168.149.25 devteam
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 52517
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;devteam.           IN  A

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.149.25#53(192.168.149.25)
;; WHEN: Tue Jul 12 08:11:49 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 25
```

**Update 2 (nslookup):**

```
nbrw:~ buildagent$ nslookup devteam
Server:     192.168.149.25
Address:    192.168.149.25#53

Name:   devteam.k-p.com
Address: 192.168.149.46
```

Git direct from OS X works fine with the hostname.

Comment: Can you run `dig @DNS_IP_ADDRESS hostname`, on your host machine, where DNS_IP_ADDRESS is the IP address of the intranet DNS server? And see if it resolves correctly? Note that by default it will try to resolve via port 53 on DNS_IP_ADDRESS.

Comment: there's no answer section?

Comment: This is the whole output that I get.

Comment: well then as you see, there is a problem with your DNS itself. Will it be possible for you to not mask your exact input and output with those XXX. I'm sure they are anyways private IPs, so nobody can access them.

Comment: Unmasked the output and added nslookup output.